# Access the FORMIK form fields values of a child component from it's parent component - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, prompt, formik

I am using **Formik** for form validation in React application.
Parent component (**Users**) - displays list of users.
If we select any user, details of the user will be displayed in another component to the right side in a form.
The child component (**UserDetails**) displays the details of the selected user.
All the details are displayed in textboxes in child component, which we can change and update the details(Here I am using FORMIK to validate fields before updating).

I have a scenario where when someone modifies the details in the form and clicks on another user without updating previous edits.
In such cases I want to show a prompt stating that "unsaved changes will be lost"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like there's a prop on `<Formik/>` to be notified of changes. From looking at the API, you could store a flag on `Users` that is toggled on any change from the currently presented form:

```
// Users

function Users() {
    const [edited, setEdited] = useState(false);
    const [active, setActive] = useState();
    return (
        <>
            <UsersList onSelect={(user) => {
                if (edited) {
                    // Notify user of unsaved changes
                } else {
                    setEdited(false);
                    setActive(user);
                }
            }}/>
            <UserDetails user={active} onEdit={() => setEdited(true)}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

```
// UserDetails

function UserDetails({ onEdit }) {
    return (
        <Formik>
            {props => (
                <input onChange={(evt) => {
                    onEdit(); // Notify parent component of an edit
                    props.handleChange(evt);
                }}/>
            )}
        </Formik>
    )
}
```

Comment: Actually this solution works. But I want to use the Formik fields or events to to notice the changes. I am okay to use any other library similar to Formik which provides notifications on field changes even to its parent component. Any suggestions please?